# SSRS map layers not rendering but can be previewed in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, gis, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm writing a map report using Visual Studio 2010 with SQL Server 2012.

The report processes and displays fine in preview within Visual Studio, however, when deployed all the map layers do not display. The grey-blue box is visible as is the legend with the correct(expected) labels so data is coming through.

When published the to excel or pdf the report still doesn't render.

Comment: Did you try exporting the report to any format (PDF, XLS)? is the result same as the one in the report view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing all but one layers it seems that there was something causing issues creating the exact same report seems to have cleared this issue.